# If $H_1$ and $H_2$ are subgroups of G, and K is a subgroup of both of them, and K is normal in G, then $H_1/K \neq H_2/K?$

Tags: abstract-algebra

My teacher posed this question in our practice exam, and implied that the answer to this question may be helpful:

If H is a subgroup of G and K is a subgroup of H and K is normal in G, then explain why H is a union of cosets of K.

My answer to that question was that the cosets of a subgroup of H partition H, therefore H is the union of the cosets of K. I'm not understanding how this implies that $H_1/K \neq H_2/K$.

Edit: Is it because $H_1$ and $H_2$ are both the unions of cosets of K, so if those cosets were the same then we would get $H_1 = H_2$, so the cosets must be different, i.e. $H_1/K \neq H_2/K$?

Comment: Well suppose that $H_1 \neq H_2$ and $K=\{e\}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Consider the epimorphism
$$\varphi:G\to G/K.$$
Then for any subgroup $H$ of $G$ containing $K$ we have
$$H=\varphi^{-1}(H/K),$$
or in terms of cosets,
$$H=\bigsqcup_{hK \in H/K} hK.$$
More generally, for any subgroup $H$ of $G$ (not necessarily containing $K$), 
$$\varphi^{-1}(\varphi(H))=HK.$$

Comment: I edited my post - does my answer make sense?

Comment: @mathiest Yes, indeed.

Comment: Thanks. That seems so obvious now. :)